# Compare strings in same column

Tags: c++, csv

I have downloaded a database of pictures.

The database comes with a CSV file that codes each picture and identifies important pixels in the picture.

The first column is a string code of the subject, something like `i000ra-fn`. The `000` is the actual code, and all strings start with an `i`. The letters after the 3 digits denote different things such as lighting, camera angle, etc.

Since there can be many pictures of subject 000, due to different lighting and camera angles, I want to only keep 1.

So what I'd like to do, is check in column 1 for the number of pictures that start with `i000`. Then randomly keep one of those and subsequently delete the rest, both in my csv file and on my hard drive.

Then I'd iterate over every name in the column until the number of subjects that I have became distinct.

I am new to c++ and can't wrap my head around how to do this. Can I get some suggestions on how to do this? So far I've loaded the csv file into a vector of vectors. The first column was skipped and loaded into a separate vector called names. I'm at a loss of how to proceed though...any suggestions?

```c++
int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    ifstream landmarksFile("muct76-opencv.csv");
    string row;
    string cell;
    vector<vector<double>> allLandmarks;
    vector<double> individualsLandmarks;
    vector<string> names;

    // skip headers
    getline(landmarksFile, row);

    // continue...
    while (getline(landmarksFile, row))
    {
        stringstream iss(row);
        while (getline(iss, cell, ','))
        {
            size_t found = cell.find("i");
            if (found != string::npos)
            {
                names.push_back(cell);
            }
            else
            {
                individualsLandmarks.push_back(atof(cell.c_str()));
            }
        }
        allLandmarks.push_back(individualsLandmarks);
        individualsLandmarks.clear();
    }
}
```

Edit: sample of CSV file...Note that the columns goes on to x75 and y75 and

```c++
name        tag x00 y00 x01 y01 x02 y02 x03
i000qa-fn   0   201 348 201 381 202 408 209
i000ra-fn   0   187 326 184 358 182 390 186
i000sa-fn   0   190 344 191 385 197 414 206
i001qa-mn   0   162 368 165 399 172 421 178
i001ra-mn   0   166 370 171 404 178 430 185
i001sa-mn   0   166 369 173 404 177 429 185
i002qa-mn   0   224 289 224 323 223 347 227
i002ra-mn   0   221 288 221 323 222 348 229
i002sa-mn   0   222 302 227 329 230 349 239
i003qa-fn   0   182 429 182 456 187 478 196
i003ra-fn   0   178 429 180 458 184 478 193
i003sa-fn   0   180 432 181 461 185 481 193
i004qa-mn   0   182 258 187 289 185 312 190
```

Downloadable here: https://code.google.com/p/muct/downloads/detail?name=muct-landmarks-v1.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Comment: Can you post the CSV file please?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I've added a sample to what the csv file looks like and also added a link to download it yourself if you are interested

Comment: "Then I'd iterate over every name in the column until the number of subjects that I have became distinct." - What do you mean by "distinct"?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Looking at my sample, `i000qa-fn` and `i000ra-fn` and `i000sa-fn` are all the same subject. They are just taken under different lighting conditions. However I want a database of just 1 picture for each subject. Therefore I would randomly remove 2 of those `i000...` pictures. `i001` is a separate subject as denoted by the fact that the digits were incremented up 1. You will notice that `i001` also has 3 different pictures based on different angles, lighting, etc. Basically I want to reduce my database to only 1 picture for each subject & the choice of which to keep should be random.

Comment: So my first thought would be to iterate over the names vector and store the first 4 characters as a local variable. Then check the rest of the vector to identify matches. Once that is done, randomly remove all except one. I'm new to C++ and I'm assuming that deleting during an iteration might cause problems. Also, since I've separated the names from the landmarks, I actually need to delete the rows from the 'allLandmarks` vector that relate to the name that was deleted...I can't wrap my head around this operation...

Answer (score 0):

1. > So what I'd like to do, is check in column 1 for the number of pictures that start with `i000`. Then randomly keep one of those and subsequently delete the rest, both in my csv file and on my hard drive.

   First, create a function which creates a vector out the elements that start with `i000`. Not too difficult...

   ```c++
   template<class Container, class UnaryOp>
   Container container_copy_if(const Container& c, UnaryOp pred)
   {
       Container temp;
       std::copy_if(std::begin(c), std::end(c), std::back_inserter(temp), pred);
       return temp;
   }

   ...

   auto vector_with_only_i000 = container_copy_if(names,
       [] (const std::string& name) {
            return name.substr("i000") != std::string::npos;
   });
   ```
2. > ...Then randomly keep one of those and subsequently delete the rest, both in my csv file and on my hard drive.

   You'll have to use a random number generator for this. Here is how it's done using `std::uniform_int_distribution`:

   ```c++
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 gen(rd());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, vector_with_only_i000.size() - 1);

   auto random_name = vector_with_only_i000.at(dist(rd()));
   ```

   Now that you have the random name you can remove everything else from the original `names` vector that doesn't equal `random_name`:

   ```c++
   auto not_equal_random_name = [&] (const std::string& name) {
       return name == random_name;
   };

   names.erase(
       std::remove_if(names.begin(), names.end(), not_equal_random_name),
       names.end());
   ```

   Now to erase them from the actual file, you'll want to do this:

   1. Save each line of from the file in a vector.
   2. Erase each element from the vector that does not equal `random_name`.
   3. Create a new file with a new name.
   4. Write the vector contents to the new file.
   5. Rename the file with the same name as the old csv file.